# Autohotkey for Press Space equest to Mouse Down

Tags: script, autohotkey, mouse-click, whitespace

I've created a SpaceBar button to MouseClick but I'm having difficulties mapping SpaceBar Press state into Mouse Down using AHK.
Anyone has the script?

Below my current Space Mouse Click script

```
#IfWinActive ahk_class Watchuwa
{
    Space::Click 
    return
}
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
#IfWinActive ahk_class Watchuwa
   Space::
      Send, {Click Down}
      KeyWait, % A_ThisHotkey
      Send, {Click Up}
      Return
```